# When will Excel's feature for stock quotes be available?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Microsoft's official website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54) tenders a video with this feature with a warning:

[image]

I can't find it on my Excel that's up to date: see [beneath](http://www.michael-saunders.com/stocksapp/pages/info.html). So when'll it be available to everybody?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot you're not an Office 365 subscriber.

You can refer to this [article's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54) NOTE:

**June 12, 2018: This feature is being made available to customers on a gradual basis over several days or weeks. It will first be available to Office Insider participants, and later to Office 365 subscribers. If you are an Office 365 subscriber, make sure you have the latest version of Office.**